# Is there a particular reason that the pendingEmits queue is limited to 1024 elements

Tags: apache-storm

I am working with Storm v1.2.1 on a cluster of 5 `r4.xlarge` EC2 nodes. Currently, I am crunching a network dataset that involves queries time-based sliding windows. After numerous trial-and-error cycles for figuring out a good-enough configuration for my use-case, I came across the `Executor` class, which maintains a member named `pendingEmits` of type `MpscChunkedArrayQueue<AddressedTuple>` (line 119 in `storm-client` module, class: `org.apache.storm.executor.Executor`). This queue has a hard-coded upper-bound of 1024 elements.

Every time I tried a configuration with my dataset, I would receive an `IllegalStateException` when Storm would attempt to add an acknowledgement tuple to `pendingEmits` with full capacity. In order to avoid getting the exception, I increased the hard-coded size of `pendingEmits` to 16534. This seems to be working (for now).

Why is `pendingEmits`'s maximum size set to 1024? Is it because of performance, or was it a random decision?

I am skeptical about this decision, because if a window consists of more than 1024 tuples (in my case each window is about 2700 tuples), the queue will become full, and the `IllegalStateException` will be thrown.

By increasing `pendingEmits` maximum size, do I jeopardize other aspects (components) of Storm?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why 1024 exactly was picked (likely for performance as you mention), but if you pull the latest version of Storm, it should be fixed https://github.com/apache/storm/pull/2676.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! It looks like this issue is resolved (?). If my input is of any worth, do you think that this can become a `Config` parameter?

Comment: Input is always appreciated :). Yes, we could add it to the config, but I'm not sure if it's worth it. The 1024 is just the initial size now, and the queue will grow to handle extra tuples if needed. If you think it should be a config parameter (and can explain why it makes sense to have), you can either write to one of the Storm mailing lists (https://storm.apache.org/getting-help.html), or raise an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: Sounds good! Again, thank you very much for your help and for your suggestion!